# Add DevExpress in AspNet Core 1.0 project

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to use DevExpress on my **AspNet Core 1.0 application (1.0.0-preview2-003121)**

But I cannot find out how to import DevExpress (XtraReport) in the `project.json`

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

Using this dependency:

```
"DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.2": "1.0.0-*"
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve 'DevExpress.XtraReports (>= 14.2.0)' for .NETFramework
```

Answer (score 1):

Officially, XtraReports don't currently support ASP.NET Core. But, there is a tricky way to add them to an MVC 6 application. Follow the [How to integrate DevExpress reporting controls for ASP.NET MVC into an MVC6 web application](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T360117) KB article to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I'm not able to run a "dotnet restore" becouse it doen't find the library.
Using this code:
"DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.2": "1.0.0-*"

I get the following error:
"Unable to resolve 'DevExpress.XtraReports (>= 14.2.0)' for .NETFramework"